# trying to understand how to not include system groups in my list of groups

Tags: linux, group

I am trying to list all the groups on a Linux system with simple `cut -d: -f1 /etc/group | sort` 
now if I am understanding right this will list all the groups in the file even the system ones, now how do I exclude them from the list ?

Comment: What are the "system" ones and how do they differ from "non-system" ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getent group | awk -F: '$3 > 999 {print $1}'
```

if "normal" groups start at `1000`